# want my users to be abble to change the userpassword

Tags: php, apache, change-password

I have a page on my website that allows the users to change their passwords

The form asks for username, current password, new password, confirm new password.

If a user enters the all information a script pops up please fill form correctly

and an error message shows

> (Notice: Undefined variable: wtbusers in
>   /home/www/hostname/dr/filename on line 16
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/www/hostname/dr/filename on line 20)

My code is pasted below, if anyone can help, It would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Tina

Changepassword information screen:

```
<div id="inlogscherm">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="changepw.php">
    <div class="textm">Change password</div><br>
    <div class="text">Username:</div><div class="invulbalkje"><? echo "{$_SESSION['username']}"; ?></div><br />
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo "{$_SESSION['username']}"; ?>">
  <div class="text">Password:</div><input name="pin" type="password" id="pin" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <div class="text">New Password:</div><input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <div class="text">Repeat New Password:</div><input name="repeatnewpassword" type="password" id="repeatnewpassword" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Change" class="button">
</form>
```

here is the php for the change.(changepw.php)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include 'db.php';


$username = $_POST['username'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];

$encrypted_password=md5($pin);
$encrypted_newpassword=md5($newpassword);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM $wtbusers WHERE  username='$username' and pin = '$pin'");
if(!$result) 
{ 
echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>"; } 
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
if($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword){
    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where   username='$username'");        
    if($sql) 
    { 
            header("location:success.php");
    }
    else
    {

       header("location:error3.php");
    }       
} else {

    header("location:error_password_not_matched.php");
}
} else {

echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>"; 
}
?>
```

If you see the problem please contact me. I will be very grateful for that!

Comment: yuu need to assign the table name to your "$wtbusers" variable , something like $wtbusers = 'users'

Comment: Please can you be more specific? $wtbusers is already my table name. Thank you

Comment: If the table name begins with $ you should avoid to use " and change for ' because everything in the quotes will be parsed by php and will say $wtbusers is not defined because in your php file you are not defining that variable.

Comment: $wtbusers may have been assigned earlier in the script and Tina has not given us that code. @Tina you could check  with `die(var_dump($wtbusers))` before you run the query against the DB. `$wtbusers` should be a string value that matches the table name in the database

Comment: @kaymus thank you, it is now successful, but the problem now is that its not updated in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notice was you haven't created a variable called ***$wtbusers***.

**$wtbusers = '`users`'; //this should be defined (change this to your whatever table name)**

Try the below code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
include 'db.php';

// print_r($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['pin'])) {
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
}
if (isset($_POST['newpassword'])) {
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
}
if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword'])) {
    $repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];
}

$encrypted_password = md5($pin);
$encrypted_newpassword = md5($newpassword);
$wtbusers = '`users`'; //this should be defined (change this to your whatever table name)

$result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM $wtbusers WHERE  username='$username' and pin = '$pin'");
if (!$result) {
    echo "<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>";
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {

    if ($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword) {

        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where   username='$username'");

        if ($sql) {
            header("location:success.php");
        }
        else {
            header("location:error3.php");
        }

    }
    else {
        header("location:error_password_not_matched.php");
    }
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, the error message is not more showing, its now successful, but there is another problem, the information is not been updated in my database. what do i do?

Comment: @Tina, your welcome..ok first of all you need to change bit in your code...i have updated the above code..please copy paste above and see the result..

Comment: i have updated my script to the above , it echoed please fill form correctly and showed this error msg  (Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_num_rows() in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 21) this is what is in my line 21 ( if(mysql_num_rows() != 0) )

Comment: i have updated my script to the above , it echoed please fill form correctly and showed this error msg  (Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_num_rows() in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 21) this is what is in my line 21 ( if(mysql_num_rows() != 0) )

Comment: Thank you, its successful now @jlocker, but still not updating my database. newpassword and repeatpassword is not updated, old password is also not updated with changed password

Comment: @Tina in your sql query i can't see that your updating your table with new password `$newpassword`..please check your sql query..Tell me the fields in your users table which you want to update the password.

Comment: new error msg (Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: pin in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: newpassword in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: repeatnewpassword in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 11) this is what i have in line 8,9,10and 11 ( $username = $_POST['username'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword']; )

Comment: @Tina please insert this before `$usename` in **changepw.php** and tell me the result.. `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: little confused please i beg if u can be more elaborate. Thank you

Comment: it showed this : Array ( [username] => 1234 [pin] => 1234 [newpassword] => 12345 [repeatnewpassword] => 12345 [Submit] => Change )

Comment: it showed this : Array ( [username] => 1234 [pin] => 1234 [newpassword] => 12345 [repeatnewpassword] => 12345 [Submit] => Change )

Comment: @Tina please update your code with my code above and tell me the result

Comment: it echoed fill password correctly and showed error msg ( Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 31) and line 31 reads ( if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) { )

Comment: @Tina please give us your website address to check this issue and contact email

Comment: can i get your email address so i can forward it to u my email is spicychi18k@yahoo.com

Comment: @Tina forward to this b320da80@opayq.com